# Is the basis for a row space the same as the basis for the column space of the same matrix but transposed?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm hoping someone could tell me the difference, if there is one, between the basis of a row space, and the basis of a transposed column space.

Or, given a matrix A, is the basis for Row A the same as the basis for Col A(transposed)?

Comment: They are same, because the rows of $A$ are the columns of the transpose of $A$. This follows from the definition of transpose. Also, avoid saying "the basis", because bases for vector spaces are not unique.